# Vectorizing Photos: Finding an Adapted Algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, vector, vectorization

As a little project, I've decided I want to write a small raster to vector converter. Lots and lots of resources are available online, but many fewer actual implementations can give me any kind of starting point. I haven't decided which language I'm going to do this in, but Python seems to be pretty adapted.

The first issue is that most papers are directed at vectorizing either logos or grayscale images, neither of which I'm too interested in. **potrace**, whose algorithm is described [here](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/potrace.pdf), is one of those libraries. Are the same techniques applicable to photo bitmaps ?

I was discouraged by my findings until I stumbled upon [Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home). The results are astonishing ! However, they don't provide any information concerning their algorithm. A method that produces similar quality results is described here: 
http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/47879/1/ID47879.pdf. The strategy is to remove the contours and process them, before drawing them as vectors.

But there is no mention of how they do this. I can extract contours with openCV, but then what ? I have trouble understanding the creation of the vector, or anything that happens after contour extraction.

So, to conclude, here are my questions: which language or library do you recommend for this project ? And do you have any tips on implementing an algorithm that can produce satisfactory results ?

Comment: [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) has code for vectorizing photos. I assume you don't want write a program that automates GIMP instead of using a library, or write it as a GIMP-fu script instead of a standalone program. But, since GIMP is open source, you can look at how the code works. I believe the basic idea is: (1) blur, (2) posterize, (3) select by color, (4) for each color, for each disconnected region, trace the border as a vector.

Comment: The simpler alternative is to just use an edge-detection algorithm, and trace each edge as a vector. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) for explanations of the edge detection algorithms, and links to further information.

Comment: Thanks for the info ! What language would you suggest ? Is Python a good choice here ?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. If you want something practical, I'd probably let GIMP do the heavy lifting, and use Python-Fu to script it internally. If you want to learn how it works, I'd start with a very simple and well-known edge-detection algorithm like [Canny's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), which you can probably find all kinds of documentation on ranging from classroom notes to heavily documented source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

- ARDECO: http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?Paper=EGSR_Ardeco@2006
  it casts the problem as an energy minimization problem, that is solved via a Voronoi-like approach
- http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~sco590/npar2011.pdf
  it is much more similar in spirit to the portrace you mentioned
- Using gradient meshes:  https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~fharhad/ganbatte/siggraph2007/CD2/content/papers/011-sun.pdf
  that represent the gradients in the image with a mesh
- Using diffusion curves:
  http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/27/47/68/PDF/diffusion_curves.pdf
  Mostly used to create art by drawing gradients, they also propose the inverse problem of vectorizing an image with their primitives.